# My Website is appearing as a blank white page in facebook canvas

Tags: facebook, facebook-canvas

I changed my app namespace and App Title within developer settings on facebook.

Now my website only appears blank. My application is in sandbox mode but I can make it public if someone needs to reproduce my issue using their facebook account.

These are the canvas urls I'm providing:

canvas url: http://books.botflip.com
secure canvas url: https://books.botflip.com

Comment: Was it working earlier? disable the sandbox mode so that we may repro the same

Comment: yes. was working earlier. sandbox disabled. heres the url: http://apps.facebook.com/botflipbooks

Comment: does my server need to respond to POST request from facebook?

Comment: M getting the error , use of this app is restricted

Comment: have you disabled the sandbox mode to make sure it is non restricted?

Comment: its only available in usa. let me turn that off

Comment: Can you post the screenshot of the app settings, hiding the secret key

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it!

It was an xframe option issue due to using rails4. Also, rails 4 requires a post route in routes.rb to work well with facebook.

[Cannot display my rails 4 app in iframe even if 'X-Frame-Options' is 'ALLOWALL'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17542511/cannot-display-my-rails-4-app-in-iframe-even-if-x-frame-options-is-allowall)

thanks for helping everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In your development.rb file:

```
config.action_dispatch.default_headers = {
  'X-Frame-Options' => 'ALLOWALL'
}
```